# How to set QPdfView's viewport background color

Tags: c++, qt, qtstylesheets, qpainter, qscrollarea

I'm trying to set a [QPdfView](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qpdfview.html)'s `viewport` background color, but unlike `QAbstractScrollArea` (from which `QPdfView`'s derived), using stylesheet does not work.

Here's how I tried to do that:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QPdfView>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QPdfView *pdfView = new QPdfView();

    pdfView->setMinimumSize(100,100);
    //I tried to set stylesheet in different ways, in multiple combinations
    //but none worked
    //pdfView->setStyleSheet("background: white");
    pdfView->setStyleSheet("QWidget{background: white;}");
    //pdfView->viewport()->setStyleSheet("background: white");

    pdfView->show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

**Note:** You need to to find and target `PdfWidgets`, so modify your `CMakeLists.txt` according the below, to be able to use `QPdfView`:

```
find_package(QT NAMES Qt6 Qt5 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Widgets PdfWidgets)
find_package(Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR} REQUIRED COMPONENTS Widgets PdfWidgets)

target_link_libraries(MyExperiments PRIVATE
     Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Widgets
     Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::PdfWidgets)
```

Here's how it looks, `viewport` is grey, and you can see the white background of `QPdfView` on the borders:

[image: PdfView with stylesheet]

I also tried to change the background color of `viewport` by overriding [QAbstractScrollArea::paintEvent](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qabstractscrollarea.html#paintEvent), and here's how:

```
void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{
    QPdfView::paintEvent(event);

    QPainter p(viewport());
    QRect rect = viewport()->rect();

    rect.adjust(-1,-1,0,0);
    p.setBrush(QBrush(QColor(0,0,100)));
    p.drawRect(rect);
}
```

But that ended up painting over `viewport`, not changing its background color, so it covers open documents, because If I use a transparent color, I can see the document through it.

I'm open to either or other ways, but I'd like to avoid using `paintEvent` if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at [QPdfView](https://github.com/qt-labs/qtpdf/blob/dev/src/pdfwidgets/qpdfview.cpp#L447)'s source code of `paintEvent`, you'll notice [QPalette::Dark](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qpalette.html#ColorRole-enum) being used to fill `viewport`, and based on that, you  can change its background color without obscuring open documents as follows:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QPdfView>
#include <QPalette>

int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    
    QPdfView view;
    
    QPalette palette = view.palette();
    palette.setBrush(QPalette::Dark, QColor("lime"));
    
    view.setPalette(palette);    
    view.show();
    
    return app.exec();
}
```

Here's the result:

[image: QPdfView viewport with lime background color]

**Note:** `QPalette::Dark` needs to be used, changes to painting the viewport will only occur if made through it.

***Source:*** [Qt Forum How to set QPdfView's viewport background color?](https://forum.qt.io/topic/145416/how-to-set-qpdfview-s-viewport-background-color?_=1685257094600)

***Credit:*** [ChrisW67](https://forum.qt.io/user/chrisw67)